# How can I create a subfolder in a documentset of a custom contenttype?

Tags: content-type, web-services, document-set

I have a custom contenttype which inherits from documentset. Further for the custom contenttype exists a custom docsethomepage.aspx (WelcomePage). Now the problem is, if I create a subfolder (contenttype: SPFolder) in the documentset the set link is wrong. Clicking on the subfolder means getting redirected to the documentsethomepage.aspx (that's the problem)

SPFolder Xml

```
< z : row xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema' ows_ContentTypeId='0x012000CE8B7947004C423CB7580EBD0958B8200061E0E27CC804418F8C868584C1C096B500E2C3ADD1BCC4294FA4F0825E9CBAE923' ows_FileLeafRef='35;#Storno' ows__dlc_DocId='AAEPW6D2E46Z-138-35' ows__dlc_DocIdUrl='http://.../_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=AAEPW6D2E46Z-138-35, AAEPW6D2E46Z-138-35' ows_ID='35' ows_ContentType='Stornierte Elemente' ...
```

An edit on the fields ows__dlc_DocId, ows__dlc_DocIdUrl, WelcomePage, ReplaceLink(old, new) didn't help.
Has anybody an idea fixing this 'bug'?

Comment: Yes the question refers to Sharepoint 2010. I've already read that this case isn't supported. But the subfolder-creation works and the correct folderview (listview) is existent. The problem is only the link, which refers to http:// servername/listname/docsethomepage.aspx and not to http:// servername/listname/docset/subfolder

Comment: so the question is, which property do I have to edit for changing the redirection link of an SPFolder-object?

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:
Custom DocumentSet Homepage with an integrated redirection section to the subfolders listviewpage.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know are folders within document sets not supported in SharePoint 2010 but in 2013. I guess your question refers to SharePoint 2010?